# AixLib 1.3.0 & 1.3.1 library is not loading in OpenModelica v1.19 & v1.20

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I wanted to use **AixLib** in OpenModelica, but it does not load.

[image]

I tried loading both AixLib 1.3.0 & 1.3.1, but neither worked. It was tested on both OpenModelica v1.19 & v1.20.

I wonder whether this is the OpenModelica compatibility issue. Is anyone using this library with OpenModelica?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce this issue. For me it's AixLib 1.3.1 is perfectly loading in OpenModelica v1.19 and I run a example model AixLib.Airflow.AirCurtain.Examples.AirCurtain too.

Comment: Thank you for checking. I wonder whether it could be an issue that OpenModelica is installed in the other drive than C. However, other libraries are working without any issues.

Comment: Can you please check the uses annotation of AixLib's package.mo file and verify you have loaded the right dependencies.  SDF(version="0.4.2"),
 Modelica_DeviceDrivers(version="2.0.0"),
    Modelica(version="4.0.0")) for AixLib 1.3.1

Comment: As for now, it seems that the problem might be caused by missing SDF. By default in OM, under SDF package it is indicated `package SDF (empty version) version="0.0.0"` and that it is a dummy package of a commercial library. Does it mean that you have the commercial package on your PC? Any way to solve this?

Comment: What is the exact log on this? 
Only few models use the SDF library, mainly one version of the heat pump model. Aside from that, you should be able to use the AixLib!